# Why Char won't print, and counter exceeded my loop;

Tags: java, multithreading, printing, runnable, simultaneous

I am trying to run this three simultaneous threads, but when I do system.print
Char won't come out, and the counter "i" went over bound.

somehow, I add an string in front of Char, it print out correctly, anyone can explain to me why is this happening?

```
    public class Part2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Runnable printA = new PrintChar('a');
        Runnable printB = new PrintChar('b');
        Runnable printC = new PrintChar('c');

        Thread t1 = new Thread(printA);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(printB);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(printC);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();     
    }

    private static class PrintChar implements Runnable { 
        private char c;
        public PrintChar(char c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void run() 
        { 
            for(int i = 1; i<=100; i++) {
                System.out.print(c + i + ", ");
            }
        } 
    } 
    }
```

/*this is the output of this code:
98, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 99, 99, .... 198, */

/*if I add a String before Char like this
This is the output I expected; */

```
        public void run() 
        { 
            for(int i = 1; i<=100; i++) {
                System.out.print("" + c + i + ", ");
            }
        }
```

/* b1, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18,.... 
a1 ~ a100
b1 ~ b100
and c1 ~ c100 runs and finish simultaneously */

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `+` operator on a `char` and an `int`, it performs arithmetic addition, not string concatenation. Putting `"" +` first means you're first doing `"" + c`, which is concatenation into a `String`, then adding that `String` to an `int`, which is another concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

`+` operator has two meanings in Java. It can represent:

- **addition** if both operands are numeric types, and `char` is considered as numeric type because internally its value is number representing position of character in Unicode Table like for [`'a'`](https://unicode-table.com/en/0061/) it would be  97 (as decimal, or 61 as hexadecimal).
- **concatenation** if at least one operand is String.

Also since evaluation goes from left to right `c + i + ", "` is equivalent of `(c + i) + ", "`. At `(c + i)` both `c` and `i` are *numeric* types so `+` represents addition and calculates `'a'+1` where `'a'` as earlier mentioned is treated as 97, so you are seeing result of `97+1` which is 98.

After that next operation is `98  + ", "` and here second operand is String, so here `+` represents concatenation. So `98 + ", "` results in String `"98, "`.

---

In case of `"" + c + i + ", "` because of left-to-right evaluation order we can express it as `(("" + c) + i) + ", "`.

- At first `("" + c)` would "calculated" and since first operand is String `+` represents concatenation, so we end up with `"" +'a'` results in String `"a"`.
- Next `"a" + i` is executed, and here also first operand is of type String so `+` also represents concatenation which results in String `"a1"`
- And finally `"a1" + ", "` is executed. Here both operands are Strings so `+` is concatenation which results in `"a1, "` string.